# map array of object Restfull API with Hapi

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, hapi

I just learned to use the **Hapi** nodejs Web Framework. I tried a test to post data in **Postman** and it worked

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "data": {
        "books": [
            {
                "id": "3aZRShPf",
                "name": "book A",
                "year": 2010,
                "author": "John Doe",
                "summary": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
                "publisher": "123",
                "pageCount": 100,
                "readPage": 20,
                "finished": false,
                "reading": false,
                "insertedAt": "2021-04-08T09:54:56.022Z",
                "updatedAt": "2021-04-08T09:54:56.022Z"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I wanted to display data like this but I failed and it returned an error

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "data": {
        "books": [
            {
                "id": "3aZRShPf",
                "name": "Book A",
                "publisher": "123"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

and this is so far i got, which part should I fix?

```
const { nanoid } = require('nanoid');
const books = require('./books');

const getAllBooks = () => ({
  status: 'success',
  data: {
    let book = books.map(book => ({id: book.id, name: book.name, publisher: book.publisher}));
    return book
  },
});
```

I'm having trouble solving it, hope you can help

Comment: And what’s the problem?

Comment: @sergdenisov I wanted to do data mapping like the data I wanted to display above but I failed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not affecting a value to books and have a return statement in your object

Solution:

```
const { nanoid } = require('nanoid');
const books = require('./books');
    
const getAllBooks = () => ({
  status: 'success',
  data: {
    books: books.map(book => ({id: book.id, name: book.name, publisher: book.publisher}))
      },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are returning `books` in `data` object. I've used [Object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

```
data: {
    books: books.map(({ id, name, publisher }) => ({ id, name, publisher })),
  },
```

```js
const obj = {
  status: "success",
  data: {
    books: [
      {
        id: "3aZRShPf",
        name: "book A",
        year: 2010,
        author: "John Doe",
        summary: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
        publisher: "123",
        pageCount: 100,
        readPage: 20,
        finished: false,
        reading: false,
        insertedAt: "2021-04-08T09:54:56.022Z",
        updatedAt: "2021-04-08T09:54:56.022Z",
      },
    ],
  },
};

const books = [
  {
    id: "3aZRShPf",
    name: "book A",
    year: 2010,
    author: "John Doe",
    summary: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
    publisher: "123",
    pageCount: 100,
    readPage: 20,
    finished: false,
    reading: false,
    insertedAt: "2021-04-08T09:54:56.022Z",
    updatedAt: "2021-04-08T09:54:56.022Z",
  },
];

const getAllBooks = () => ({
  status: "success",
  data: {
    books: books.map(({ id, name, publisher }) => ({ id, name, publisher })),
  },
});

const result = getAllBooks();
console.log( result );
```